# What refactoring tools do you use for .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, refactoring

Do you use any of the refactoring tools like DevExpress' Refactor Pro? Which tool do you use and why?

I'm looking for recommendations. Ideally I'd like open source tool that works with VB and C# inside VS2005 and VS2008. If I had to narrow down my list of ideals, I would purchase something for VS2008. Not sure on the language choice, probably VB for now.

Answer (score 20):

I can't recommend [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) highly enough. It's not free or open source though. Starts from $US199 for the personal edition that works with both C# and VB.NET

Comment: agree++ on Resharper. It makes nearly impossible refactorings almost trivial and implements a good sense of how code can be improved.

Comment: Unfortunately, ReSharper doesn't like big solutions, Visual Studio bogs down into an unusable state when I open my class library, even with solution-wide analysis turned off. DevExpress tools doesn't have that problem though.

Comment: I've found that if you have enough memory, ReSharper works reasonably well with large solutions. Still, I tend to create a "meta-solution" when I'm refactoring public members used in multiple solutions. Other than that, I do try to keep solutions down to 1 dozen projects or so.

Comment: Resharper can be slow with big solutions.  The latest release 4.5 is much faster and uses less memory.  Even running slowly, I know I can get more done in less time with Resharper.

Comment: +1 my employer wouldn't purchase me a copy so I purchased my own and I would recommend anyone to do the same!

Comment: The performance of ReSharper 4.5 is improved significantly over previous versions...worth upgrading if you're having slowdown issues.

Answer (score 11):

[CodeRush, Xpress edition for Visual Studio is free](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)

There is also a series of [webcasted tutorials](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/quickstart.xml) available

Comment: I recommend CodeRush over ReSharper on my own experience. Resharper made VS2008 really unusable to the point that I had to uninstall it. There is a big issue with a large solution, which is hard for me to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't recommend Coderush, even simple tasks as renaming (refactoring) method doesn't work the way one would expect (renames just method in the file, not in entire solution, lol)

Answer (score 4):

Big tick for [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), not only a productivity booster with on-the-fly error checking, but also on-the-fly suggestions on cleaner/better ways of doing things, including new naming convention suggestions in latest version. A tool that teaches.

Comment: +1 for "a tool that teaches", especially for some of the C# syntax changes in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3):

For an alternative to ReSharper, try [DevExpress Refactor! Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/).

Comment: Refactor Pro!, along with CodeRush (Refactor! comes with it IIRC), are simply awesome and the visual eye candy is sweet. I wouldn't mind trying ReSharper but haven't gotten around to it. I'm probably a little biased; I attended Mark Miller's session at a codecamp and watching him work his magic got me hooked.

Comment: I have licenses for both Refactor! Pro and ReSharper, and I actually like ReSharper more, but I find it a bit unstable when I work on big solutions, like my class library, but I swapped back to ReSharper now and it actually seems to run stable for now, so perhaps it conflicted with another addin I have had installed, not that I know what that would be. Personally I don't install CodeRush though, I find all the eye-candy it brings a bit too much.

Answer (score 2):

Code Style Enforcer is one of the add-on maninly for code refactoring. you download and install and it's a freeware too.